# Search for specific lines from a file

Tags: windows, perl, directory

I have an array that contains the data from a text file.

I want to filter the array and copy some information to another array. `grep` seems to not work.

Here's what I have

```
$file = 'files.txt';

open (FH, "< $file") or die "Can't open $file for read: $!";
@lines = <FH>;
close FH or die "Cannot close $file: $!";

chomp(@lines);

foreach $y (@lines){

    if ( $y =~ /(?:[^\\]*\\|^)[^\\]*$/g ) {
        print $1, pos $y, "\n";
    }
}
```

#### files.txt

```
public_html
Trainings and Events
General Office\Resources
General Office\Travel
General Office\Office Opperations\Contacts
General Office\Office Opperations\Coordinator Operations
public_html\Accordion\dependencies\.svn\tmp\prop-base
public_html\Accordion\dependencies\.svn\tmp\props
public_html\Accordion\dependencies\.svn\tmp\text-base
```

The regular expression should take the last one or two folders and put them into their own array for printing.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel, `File::Spec` to the rescue : http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html

Answer (score 7):

A regex can get very picky for this. It is far easier to split the path into components and then count off as many as you need.  And there is a tool for this exact purpose, the core module [File::Spec](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html), as mentioned by [xxfelixxx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1799189/xxfelixxx) in a comment.

You can use its `splitdir` to break up the path, and `catdir` to compose one.

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use File::Spec::Functions qw(splitdir catdir);

my $file = 'files.txt';    
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my @dirs;    
while (<$fh>) {
    next if /^\s*$/;  # skip empty lines
    chomp;

    my @path = splitdir $_;

    push @dirs, (@path >= 2 ? catdir @path[-2,-1] : @path);
}
close $fh;

say for @dirs;
```

I use the module's functional interface while for heavier work you want its object oriented one. Reading the whole file into an array has its uses but in general process line by line.  The list manipulations can be done more elegantly but I went for simplicity.

I'd like to add a few general comments

- *Always* start your programs with `use strict` and `use warnings`
- Use lexical filehandles, `my $fh` instead of `FH`
- Being aware of (at least) a dozen-or-two of most used modules is *really* helpful. For example, in the above code we never had to even mention the separator `\`.

Comment: There's no need to copy the whole file to `@lines`. A simple `while ( <$fh> )` would be better.

Comment: @Borodin  By all means -- I meant to keep their code.  But, it is better to change some of it.  Thank you.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much, I will have to read up on how it all works.

Comment: @cacartano You are most welcome :).  Yes, read up on the module -- it's farily simple.  If any of the code needs explanation let me know, I'll add.

Answer (score 2):

I can't write a full answer because I'm using my phone. In any case **zdim** has mostly answered you. But my solution would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use File::Spec::Functions qw/ splitdir catdir /;

my $file = 'files.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $file or die qq{Unable to open "$file" for input: $!};

my @results;

while ( <$fh> ) {
    next unless /\S/;
    chomp;
    my @path = splitdir($_);
    shift @path while @path > 2;
    push @results, catdir @path;
}

print "$_\n" for @results;
```